# Problem with justification and \titleformat (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, luatex

I am using this titleformat for my chapters but the text after \chapter{} ist centered too.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
  {\centering\textbf{---~~\thechapter~~---}}{-10pt}
  {\hrulefill\LARGE\sffamily\centering\vskip-0pt\textbf{#1}\vskip-10pt\hrulefill}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
```

How can i justify the text?

Comment: Have you tried placing it between `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` instead of `\centering`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay i found the mistake. The titleformat wasn't wrong. There was a \centering{} on my titlepage and i changed it to {\centering}. The Text is justified now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a typing mistake in another place of the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the same problem as you. The problem  must have another origin.

On an other hand, you should use the tools supplied by the package, and simplify you \titleformat command. You can use this code, which results in a chapter title that is very close to the one obtained with your code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
{\Large ---~~\thechapter~~---}{9pt}
{\titlerule[0.8pt]\vskip9pt\LARGE\textbf{#1}\vskip9pt\titlerule[0.8pt]}`
```